# Не работает поиск с условием в mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Элементы коллекции выглядят так:

```js
{
  settings: {
    starboard: {
      channelID: '1129422168984387594',
      reqReacts: 1,
      data: [Map],
      customReact: '⭐'
    },
    neuro: { search: true }
  },
  _id: new ObjectId("649e9d53188b7e7bb4f02cef"),
  __v: 0,
}
```

`settings.neuro.search` стоит на `true` только у 1 элемента коллекции (его пример выше).

Я ввожу следующий код:

```js
Collection.find({ 'settings.neuro.search': {$ne : false}}).then(function(results) {
console.log(results)
})
```

В консоль отправляются все элементы коллекции, даже те, у которых `settings.neuro.search` стоит на `false`.

В чем может заключаться проблема?

Comment: Я не большой специалист, но здесь у меня подозрение сразу на $ne: false. Почему не попробовать просто true? Может $ne барахлит с логическими значениями?

Comment: @Vasily, это помогло. Но как тогда быть со строками? Там тоже выводятся все элементы

Comment: Не понимаю вопроса. С какими строками? Где выводятся все элементы?
По работающему запросу о котором вопрос вам должен вывестись один документа из коллекции.